# Textblock text not wrapping in wp7 app

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

new to wp7 and i have not the faintest idea why the textblock text is not wrapping?

```
<Popup x:Name="EulaPopUp" IsOpen="False">
            <Grid Background="White"  Width="{Binding ElementName=LayoutRoot, Path=Width}" Height="{Binding ElementName=LayoutRoot, Path=Height}">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Text="End User License Agreement" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="0"/>
                <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="scrollViewer1" Width="{Binding ElementName=ContentPanel, Path=Width}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,30,0,0" Grid.Row="1">
                    <TextBlock Name="eulaTxt" Width="{Binding ElementName=ContentPanel, Path=Width}" Text="{Binding Path=AppResources.EULA, Source={StaticResource AppResources} }" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            </ScrollViewer>
            <Button Grid.Row="2" Content="I Agree" Background="Green" Height="70" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Name="EulaOK" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="160" />
            </Grid>
        </Popup>
```

I'm binding the widths of the elements so that when the device reorients the widths adjust accordingly. Is this wrong? How can I fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

U can actually customize ur message box..something like this ...

```
 public static void customizedMessageBox(int messageboxtype, string title, string text, IEnumerable<string> buttons, int focusbutton, MessageBoxIcon icon, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        if (!Guide.IsVisible)
        {
            try
            {
                ProgressBarControl.dismissProgressBar();
                Guide.BeginShowMessageBox(" ", text, buttons, focusbutton, MessageBoxIcon.None, callback, state);
                messageboxType = messageboxtype;
            }
            catch (GuideAlreadyVisibleException ex)
            {
                Logger.log("MsgBox", "Exception : messageboxtype: " + messageboxtype
                    + "\n" + ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
        //return messageboxtype;
    }
```

and for ur text wrapping query.. I have the same type of design in my app..i.e, Eula screen to present the license agreement .. what we have used is something like this..

```
<Grid x:Name="EulaGrid" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <ListBox x:Name="lbEula" Margin="18,100,19,135" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Style="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle1}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"
                           TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                           IsHitTestVisible="False"
                           Width="Auto" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="18" Foreground="Black" x:Name="eulaText" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="2"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

make the width Auto so that it will adjust accordingly for both orientations.. I hope it helps u.. Gud luck :)

Comment: Tried that already (Guide.BeginShowMessageBox), it cuts off text longer than 256 characters.

Comment: then try the second option.. the xaml part..it will help..We are actually using list box which contains the text block.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious as to why you're not using a [MessageBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.messagebox%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to show the License Agreement in, rather than attempting to re-create it as a custom control?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but MessageBox isn't highly customisable, I can't even provide custom Labels on the buttons, and i also think there's a limit to the number of characters that can be displayed in a messagebox?

Comment: If your EULA extends that limit, you got other, more serious, problems. (Also, not providing a "Disagree" button to a EULA, makes it invalid)

Comment: Honestly its amazing the sort of limitations wp7 has but considering its microsoft no surprise there, I ended up going with this guy's scrollable textblock http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/09/08/creating-scrollable-textblock-for-wp7.aspx and yeah the logic for the agree button too is being tackled. So much unnecessary distractions from the main objective of the app.. sigh..